# New to c++, not returning value after function, calc.cpp

Tags: c++, return-value, calculator

I have a basic issue that hopefully someone here can help me with. I'm quite confident it's a small, forgetful type of issue, missing return or something similar.

```
///////////////////////////
//My Basic Calculator App
//Written by l8nit3tr0ubl3
//of NottaDev inc.
///////////////////////////

#include <iostream>

void in() //Take input from user, all 3 variables.
{
    int add(int, int); //Forward declarations
    int minus(int, int);
    int divide(int, int);
    int multiply(int, int);//end declarations

    std::cout << "My Basic Calculator\n";//take inputs
    std::cout << "Please input your first number.\n";
    int firstNumber;
    std::cin >> firstNumber;
    std::cout << "Choose math function.\n";
    std::cout << "Eg. *-+/\n";
    char operatorType;
    std::cin >> operatorType;
    std::cout << "Please input second number.\n";
    int secondNumber;
    std::cin >> secondNumber;//end inputs

    if (operatorType == '+') //determine math function to use
        add(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    else if (operatorType == '-')
        minus(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    else if (operatorType == '/')
        divide(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    else if (operatorType == '*')
        multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber);//end math function
}

int add(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) //Actual math is done
{
    return firstNumber  + secondNumber;
}
int minus(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
{
    return firstNumber  - secondNumber;
}
int divide(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
{
    return firstNumber  / secondNumber;
}
int multiply(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
{
    return firstNumber  * secondNumber; //End math
}

int main()
{
    in(); //Call input, which will call math function
    return 0; //return '0' for no error.
}
```

Can somebody please tell me what ive forgotten to call or return??

I should have been more precise on my question and i apologize for not doing so. There are no errors produced, i was simply unable to echo my answer to console. However there is a perfect answer supplied below

Comment: Do you have any errors reported?

Comment: *a basic issue* is unclear. What problem are you having? And choose a better title that describes the problem.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what is the problem, otherwise i see no problem at all.

Comment: Well, calling it without input is interesting: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e97a6c79450f88a4 As an aside, don't repeat yourself (DRY): Avoid forward-declarations.

Comment: I'm am using xcode, and visual studio (depending on which os im using at the time) and both seem to stop when user input is required. However looking at your link i see the issue you are referring to. I had the same result trying to compile on my ipad.    OP changed to be more clear with question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `add`, `multiply` etc. functions return the result of the operation, but you're not doing anything with it.

You could for example print it:

```
std::cout << add(firstNumber, secondNumber) << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, i assumed the "return" function would give me a 'cout' but was obviously wrong. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want to output the result of your calculations.
So write

`std::cout << add(firstNumber, secondNumber);`

But even nicer it is, if you do the output only once. For this use a temprary variable, for example

```
result = add(firstNumber, secondNumber);
```

...

```
std::cout << "The result is " << result << std:endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your add, multiply and minus functions are returning back to void in(), and you have no variable assigned to them when they are returned.